# Who can explain this?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I am having trouble understanding this comment.

```
Array({:a => "a", :b => "b"}) #=> [[:a, "a"], [:b, "b"]]
```

Could you explain how it works in detail?

Comment: Please take the time to come up with a much better title for your question(s). "Who can example this?" can apply to a myriad of topics and questions.

Answer (score 5):

`{:a => "a", :b => "b"}` creates a Hash.
Passing that to `Array` will create an array of arrays. Each array element of the outer array will be another array containing the key and the value of one item of the hash.

Comment: Why :a is key and "a" is value?

Comment: Well, that's the syntax: `<key> => <value>`. There is nothing special here.

Answer (score 5):

The `Array` methods transforms your hash into an array.
Therefore, for each entry of the hash, ruby will create an array with two elements : the key and the value of the entry in the hash.

You have two entries in your array :

`:a => "a"` which becomes `[:a, "a"]`
`:b => "b"` which becomes `[:b, "b"]`

Comment: Why :a is key and "a" is value?

Comment: Because in your hash, :a is a key and "a" is a value.

Comment: `Array({'a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd'})` would result in `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]`

Answer (score 5):

It's actually a method provided by Kernel module.

Firstly it tries to call `to_ary`(return self for array), then `to_a` on argument.

You'll get the same result by using corresponding methods `to_ary` and `to_a`.

Comment: Why :a is key and "a" is value?